# How to manage components/widgets which can be added/removed dynamically by the end user

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, widget, flux, reactjs-flux

We're currently building a web app using React in which the user has the ability to add/remove widgets on a specific page.

For example, he has a customizable dashboard to which he can add lists/calendars/tables/etc. Those widgets would receive their data from Flux stores, however, each widget would only have access to it's own state, so the store state would look like this:

```
this.state = {
  widgetStates: {
    listWidget1: {...},
    tableWidget1: {...},
    tableWidget2: {...},
    ...
  }
}
```

The widget with the id "tableWidget1" would then only have access to it's specific state in that store.

How does one approach this? How and where should we store the information about which widgets should be rendered and how they should be rendered?

Maybe our whole approach is wrong, so we're open for advice in any regard.

**Edit: Further clarification.**

Let's say I have a UserDataGrid component like this:

```
const UserDataGrid = ({id, users, sortDirection, onSortChange, isFetching}) => {
    return (
        <DataGrid id={id} rows={users} isLoading={isFetching}>
            <Header>
                <SortableHeaderCell property="id" onSortChange={onSortChange} sortDirection={sortDirection}>
                    Id
                </SortableHeaderCell>
                <SortableHeaderCell property="displayName" onSortChange={onSortChange} sortDirection={sortDirection}>
                    Name
                </SortableHeaderCell>
                <SortableHeaderCell property="points" onSortChange={onSortChange} sortDirection={sortDirection}>
                    CPU
                </SortableHeaderCell>
            </Header>
            <Column>
                <TextCell property="id"/>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <TextCell property="displayName"/>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <NumberCell property="points" digits={2}/>
            </Column>
        </DataGrid>
    );
};
```

On the dashboard, I have a "+"-button, which would show me a list of the addable widgets.

The user now adds the UserDataGrid to his dashboard.

Thus, we now have to populate the state of the widget in our store. Once that is done, we can render the widget with the data from the store.

The problem is that these widgets may be interactive (see the sortable headers in the UserDataGrid component). I want to avoid having to implement all the interaction-handling code in the Component containing the widgets, since it shouldn't know how to handle it's children's actions, according to separation of concerns.

In other words: widgetStates[UserDataGridInstance42] wouldn't be a simple object but rather a small store which is used by UserDataGridInstance42, so UserDataGrid would define it's own action handlers which would be executed on the "store" when an action from a UserDataGrid instance is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, this is the user scenario I got from your question:

> 1. User goes to an admin panel
> 2. In a checkbox he can choose which widgets to use
> 3. Once he has selected a widget, the widget appears in the admin panel

Hopefully, I'm correct. 
If so, you could apply some sort of a lazy-loading mechanism. You could dispatch an action that loads the info for the new widget.

But, let's put lazy loading aside for a moment.
Once tableWidget1 is selected, you set its state to true and just upload the component using something like

```
{this.state.widgetStates.tableWidget1 ? <TableWidget1 /> : null}
```

That's it basically.
You could load the widgetStates from the server and add server side rendering, and so on....

Comment: You got the use case (in its essence) right, but I think your solution doesn't cover it completely. I have edited the question with some more clarifying info. Thanks for your effort so far!